# Why is bootstrap navbar not centering child elements in simple code sample?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[Click here for the display output -> http://www.bootply.com/VtPTgKeCLO](http://www.bootply.com/VtPTgKeCLO)

This is the following code

```
     <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom top-main-navbar">

            <div class="container">

                    <div class="navbar-header">

                        <div class="navbar-brand">

                                            Brand © 2015

                        </div>

                    </div>

                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav nav">
                        <li>About</li>
                        <li>Developers</li>
                        <li>Cool Stuff</li>                 
                    </ul>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"></div>    
                </div>

            </div>




    </nav>
```

The list items do not get centered(vertically) in the navbar

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to wrap the `<li>` content in `<a>` for Bootstrap's styles to apply paddings and thus center vertically.

**[Example](http://www.bootply.com/9cNv15M3Dm)**

Answer (score 1):

You have no links in the navbar. It's `.nav>li>a` that have styles for centering vertically.

Try this:

```
...

<ul class="navbar-nav nav">
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#developers">Developers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#cool-stuff">Cool Stuff</a></li>                 
</ul>

...
```